# Laravel - How to unit test a middleware updating user's data using mockery

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I have the following middleware to update the user's `last_seen_at` field and I've used it only for routes that an authenticated user can call it:

```php
// app/Http/Middleware/LastSeen.php

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    $user->last_seen_at = now();

    $user->save();

    return $next($request);
}
```

```php
// app/Http/Kernel.php

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other middleware
    'lastseen' => \App\Http\Middleware\LastSeen::class
]
```

```php
// routes/api.php

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['jwt', 'lastseen']
], function () {
    // routes
});
```

I've written the following unit test for testing the middleware:

```php
// tests/Unit/LastSeenMiddlewareTest.php

/** @test */
public function doesLastSeenMiddlewareUpdateUsersLastSeenAt()
{
    $user = Mockery::mock(User::class);

    $user->shouldReceive('setAttribute')->passthru();
    $user->shouldReceive('save')->once();

    $user = $user->makePartial();

    app()->instance(User::class, $user);

    $request = Mockery::mock(Request::class)
        ->shouldReceive('user')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn()
        ->getMock();

    $middleware = new LastSeen;

    $middleware->handle($request, function () {});
}
```

By running the test, I get an error: `ErrorException: Creating default object from empty value`. However, I don't understand the issue to be able to solve it.

Comment: i will test it with a feature test.Basically, create a route in your test with the middleware assigned, visit the route, assert the updated `last_seen` on the logged user Check this post https://laravel-news.com/testing-laravel-middleware

Comment: @ml59 So you say it's not possible to do a unit test? Previous developers wrote unit tests for most of the middleware they've implemented. I just wanted to be consistent.

Comment: I never say that. There a lot of discussion in the Laravel community how to test `Middleware`,`Request` etc. Some do it with Unit test some with Feature test.  If you want to unit test you will have to mock a lot of things, write complicated code, less readable. I suggested you the Feature test since it is easier.
In the article (link above) you can find more infos frem the creator of the framework about the practice Unit vs Feature

Comment: @ml59 Uh, I found the issue. It was kinda stupid. I've posted an answer myself. It was not really complicated. I like to know your opinion about that. Is my test OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was stupid from the beginning. I missed passing `$user` as the return value for the `user` method of the mocked `Request`. The following test passes:

```php
// tests/Unit/LastSeenMiddlewareTest.php

/** @test */
public function doesLastSeenMiddlewareUpdateUsersLastSeenAt()
{
    $user = Mockery::mock(User::class);

    /* As I'm making a partial mock,
       I don't need to worry about passing
       through the call to the setAttribute method */

    $user->shouldReceive('save')->once();

    $user = $user->makePartial();

    app()->instance(User::class, $user);

    $request = Mockery::mock(Request::class)
        ->shouldReceive('user')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($user) // I should've passed $user here
        ->getMock();

    $middleware = new LastSeen;

    $middleware->handle($request, function () {});

    $this->assertEqualsWithDelta($user->last_seen_at, now(), 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, middlaware is just a classic `class` with an `handle` method.
I will unit test like this:

```
  public function doesLastSeenMiddlewareUpdateUsersLastSeenAt()
    {
        //note: this is using the old factory syntax prior to Laravel 8 https://github.com/laravel/legacy-factories
        $user = factory(User::class)->create(['last_seen_at' => now()->subHour()]);
        
        //login as the user since in your middleware you get the logged user
        $this->actingAs($user);
        
        //get the middleware through the container
        $middleware = app(LastSeen::class);
        
        //call handle method
        $middleware->handle(request(),  function () {});
        $this->assertEqualsWithDelta($user->refresh()->last_seen_at, now(), 1);
    }
```

Comment: You're creating a real user and user authentication. Isn't that bad for a unit test? As far as I understood, for unit testing, a unit must be isolated. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Something caught my eyes in your answer. Why getting middleware through the container and not instantiating it directly? Is there a benefit?

Comment: It's a good practice to use the container to get new instance. It will resolve dependency automatically. In that middleware case, you can make  `new LastSeen` it wil be the same result

Comment: What's your answer to my first comment? Thanks.

Comment: In unit testing we are looking to test a specific method or assert a value. The point is not testing a whole feature. This is what i am doing. You can mock or use factory. Personnaly, i am not a fan of mocking everything and make the test a lot less readable and hard of debugging for the same result. Just use the faster way